# Customize syntax highlighting colors of data types and variables for typescript in Visual Studio Code

Tags: themes, visual-studio-code, customization, syntax-highlighting

I would like customize syntax highlighting colors for typescript.

I use  Visual Studio Code 1.16 and custom theme [(Actual) Obsidian](https://github.com/zeh/vsc-theme-actual-obsidian).

I try use featues [editor.tokenColorCustomizations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes).

Here is my custom user settings.

```
{
        "editor.fontSize": 20,
        "workbench.colorTheme": "(Actual) Obsidian",
        "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
            "functions": "#F1F1F1",
            "keywords": "#8EC160",
            "types": "#87CEEB",
            "numbers": "#F1F1F1",
            "variables": "#F1F1F1",
            "textMateRules": [              
            ]   
        }
}
```

I don’t know how can I select a change color of:

- data types keywords (in the screenshot string, number, boolen)
- variables (in the screenshot : filtredProducst)
- in the screenshot: OnInit

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 15):

You're on the right track.

As you've seen, `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` can be used to set broad classes of tokens like "keywords", etc.  The exact set of things that can be customized this way does not appear to be documented, but you can refer to the source code for [`ITokenColorCustomizations`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1.37.1/src/vs/workbench/services/themes/common/workbenchThemeService.ts#L71-L81).

Then there is the `textMateRules` section.  This can be used to specify things that the "simple" method cannot.  The [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes) explains the basic idea, but a screenshot may help to illustrate:

[image: Screenshot showing how to customize syntax colors]

First, use the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) to run "Developer: Inspect TM Scopes".  This pops up a window that will show the sequence of scope labels for any token.

Edit 2020-07-24: As of VSCode 1.47 (and possibly a little earlier) the command is called "**Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes**".

Next, add an entry to `textMateRules` where the `scope` specifier matches the stack of scope labels.  The [matching rules](https://macromates.com/manual/en/scope_selectors) are somewhat complicated but mostly intuitive; you'll probably get it pretty quickly just by experimenting.  Changes to the rules take effect as soon as you save `settings.json`.

Note: VSCode does not appear to completely or correctly implement the TextMate matching rules.  It's close, but that's it.  (Examples: VSCode does not implement exclusion with "-", and its resolution of "a c" versus "b c" seems incorrect.)

For the specific elements in your question:

- Data types can be matched with `support.type.primitive`
- `filteredProducts` can be matched with `variable.other.property`
- `OnInit` can be matched with `entity.other.inherited-class`

Example (that just makes them all red):

```
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": [
                    "support.type.primitive",
                    "variable.other.property",
                    "entity.other.inherited-class",
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#F00",
                },
            },
        ],
```

---

Update 2023-10-13: All of the above is assuming one is using the syntax highlighting based on TextMate grammars, which work on individual files in isolation and identify syntactic elements using regular expressions.  At some point VSCode added "semantic highlighting", which allows highlighting to use information from a language server that does a "real" parse (e.g., looking at header files in C/C++), making it potentially more accurate and expressive.  See the VSCode [Semantic Highlight Guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide) for more information on that alternative mechanism.

Comment: Developer Run TM scopes command is no longer available in VS code.

Comment: @Kunok The command name has changed; updated answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answer may be out of date.

Currently, it looks like the right answer is to add a setting to settings.json along these lines:

```
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "enabled": true,
    "rules": {
        "type": {
            "foreground": "#ff0000"
        }
    }
}
```

See: [What is the token name for types in VSCode Typescript syntax highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68852453/what-is-the-token-name-for-types-in-vscode-typescript-syntax-highlighting)