# Extending VS Code syntax highlighting

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

Is there a way to extend Visual Studio Code syntax highlighting for specific items using the user settings (or similar methods not involving writing an extension)?

I am using a color theme but would like to change the syntax colouring for a specific namespace of HTML tags, e.g.

`<div></div>` uses standard colouring from theme

`<ext:div></ext:div>` uses a different color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, there is nothing in VSCode proper (no extensions) that will highlight an arbitrary regex.  (Well, there is the Search feature, but the highlighting from that is temporary.)

Short of writing an extension or using an existing one that does this, the most capable method of highlight customization is the `textMateRules` mechanism of [`editor.tokenCustomizations`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme) in `settings.json`.

Now, the built-in TextMate grammar simply classifies "ext:div" as unrecognized, so the best possible with this approach is to change the highlighting for all unrecognized tags.  That would look like this:

```
    // https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": [
                    "meta.tag.other entity.name.tag",
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#080",
                    "fontStyle": "bold",
                },
            },
        ],
    },
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of using textMateRules to match ext:div tag]

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57764371/2659307) that goes through the process of adding `textMateRules` in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't find a better, more standard way to do this, the extension [TODO Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wayou.vscode-todo-highlight) would work for you.  It is typically used to highlight special comments for yourself like "FIXME" but could be used in your case with a regex like:

```
  "todohighlight.keywordsPattern": "\\s*<\\s*\\/{0,1}ext:.*\\s*>",
```

And then you can set the coloring any way you want:

```
"todohighlight.defaultStyle": {
    "color": "red",
    // "letterSpacing": "1px",
    // "backgroundColor": "rgba(170,102,0,1)",
    "backgroundColor": "transparent"
    // "borderRadius": "4px",
    "isWholeLine": false
},
```

Comment: That is a very interesting idea, thank you. Only problem with this is, that I am currently using the TODO extension for highlighting my TODOs ;) I might just try to write a similar decorator for my purposes. I was just hoping that there was an easy way to extend the syntax highlighting that is currently in use.

Comment: Yes, it is not the best option but may be the only option.  There is no reason you can't continue to use TODO to highlight TODO's, etc.  You just add on to the keyWordsPattern regex with an "or" | .

Comment: I ended up going with this to complement the Yarn Spinner extension for yarn files. Thank you!