# Visual Studio Code - meaning of syntax highlight colors

Tags: syntax, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, highlight

I'm looking for a reference as to what each color of syntax highlighting in Visual Studio Code actually means. I'm currently using the dark default theme Dark+. I've gotten used to recognizing a few of the highlight colors and I get the gist of what I'm looking at, but I'm looking for a more detailed reference of what each color means.
I've searched for a while for this and can not find any reference guide or glossary/index listing the colors and meanings. Not sure if it matters, but I am solely writing in JavaScript.
Thank you in advance.

edit: I have included a screenshot of the type of syntax highlighting I am referring to.

[image: syntax highlighting]

Comment: Could you give an example of what colour(s) you are seeing / are confusing you? Also are you using git?

Comment: I have included a screenshot of a simple function to showcase a few of the colors. I am not yet using git.

Comment: I probably should have said earlier - if you hover over any errors in VSC it normally tells you exactly what it's finding fault with. You can then use that information to resolve your issue. I'll have a closer look at this later in any case!

Comment: @AJC24 I'm not having any errors with this code, and I am somewhat familiar with that function in VSC, but thank you! What I'm looking for is a list/glossary of what each color in the code represents. For example 'function' is blue, and 'if/else' are pink. Is there a list anywhere that describes what the colors mean? Like, why do 'function' and 'NaN' share the same color?

Comment: The specific colors will change with each theme you use.  You might be able to look in the source code for the theme you are using and find a mapping of colors to language tokens/name: https://github.com/vangware/dark-plus-material

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The meaning of the syntax highlight colors comes in two parts:

1. How are the characters in the file organized into meaningful tokens?
2. How are those tokens assigned a particular color and font style?

### Partitioning text to tokens

The first part is determined by a grammar description built in to VSCode.  VSCode uses a system based on [TextMate grammars](https://macromates.com/manual/en/language_grammars).  The grammars are defined in the VSCode sources (e.g., [JavaScript.tmLanguage.json](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/javascript/syntaxes/JavaScript.tmLanguage.json)), but in that form have gone through a couple stages of postprocessing, making them nearly unreadable.  There is no documentation of the intent of these grammar files.  They tend to at least roughly follow the relevant language specification, but with plenty of ad-hoc deviations.

The most practical way to understand what tokens are defined is to use the "Developer: Inspect TM Scopes" tool available in the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P).  When you put your cursor on a token, it will show you the "scope labels" that describe that token.  These labels are more or less human-readable.

Edit 2020-07-24: As of VSCode 1.47 (and possibly a little earlier) the command is called "**Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes**".

Example:

[image: Screenshot of the TM Scope Inspector]

Above, we can see that the `return` keyword is most specifically classified as `keyword.control.flow.js`.  It is within a brace-enclosed code block (`meta.block.js`), within a function definition (`meta.function.js`), within Javascript source code (`source.js`).

That sequence of scope labels is the closest thing there is to a "meaning" for a token in VSCode.

### Assigning colors to tokens

Next, there is the process of mapping that sequence of scope labels to a color and font style.  That is done by the theme.  In my case I am using Visual Studio Light, defined in the VSCode sources in [light_vs.json](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/theme-defaults/themes/light_vs.json).  In the case of the `return` keyword, this is the applicable fragment:

```
        {
            "scope": "keyword.control",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#0000ff"
            }
        },
```

This says, basically, that anything with a scope label beginning with "keyword.control" shall have a blue color.  But other fragments may override this one; the [rules](https://macromates.com/manual/en/scope_selectors) are somewhat complex.  Why blue?  It's an arbitrary aesthetic choice.

Why do `function` and `NaN` have the same color?  The grammar assigns them different scope labels (`storage.type.function.js` versus `constant.language.nan.js`), but it just happens that the theme you are using (Dark+) assigns them the same color (as does mine).  I find that an odd choice, but can only speculate about the reason.

### Customizing the colors

You didn't ask, but an obvious follow-on question would be how to customize these colors, for example giving `function` and `NaN` different colors.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57764371/2659307).

Comment: it feels like the textmate scopes is like css classes, which have inheritance, right?

Comment: The design of TM scopes looks to me like it was somewhat based on CSS, but simplified.  The answer links to the [details](https://macromates.com/manual/en/scope_selectors).

Answer (score 0):

The following roughly applies to Python, at least.

```
Orange = string
yellow = function/method
brownish green = comment
very light green = number, "+-*/=><"
bright green = class, module
white = modules unknown to VS code? Functions from modules (e.g., the ".sort" in "np.sort")
light blue = variable
dark blue = "class", "def", "False", "not", "None", "in", ... (= "other reserved words"?)
purple = command (while, for, if, try, except, return, ...)
```

I have some variables in white, for no obvious reason. Please, improve this answer.