# What is the token name for types in VSCode Typescript syntax highlighting?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I'd like to change the styling of my VSCode syntax highlighting, so that I can differentiate between types and classes.

```
class Thing; // should be one color
type ThingT; // should be another color
```

What is the name the token name I would need to specify? Will I need [TODO Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wayou.vscode-todo-highlight)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Customize syntax highlighting colors of data types and variables for typescript in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46452646/customize-syntax-highlighting-colors-of-data-types-and-variables-for-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The foreground color of `class` uses the scope `entity.name.type.class.ts`. `type` uses `entity.name.type.alias.ts`.

**Update:** If overriding in `settings.json`, use:

```json
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "enabled": true,
    "rules": {
        "type": {
            "foreground": "#ff0000" // color here
        }
    }
}
```

---

FYI, you can see scopes with the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` command. For example, I got this for my TypeScript class:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| language | `typescript` |
| standard token type | `Other` |
| foreground | `#FFCB6B` |
| background | `#0F0F0F` |
| contrast ratio | `12.78` |
| --- | --- |
| textmate scopes | `entity.name.type.class.ts` `meta.class.ts` `source.ts` |
| foreground | `entity.name.type.class` `{ "foreground": "#FFCB6B" }` |

[image: View Scopes Command]

[image: Screenshot]

You might also use the `Developer: Generate Color Theme From Current Settings` command:

[image: generate theme]

[image: generated theme token]

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to keep class coloring as default and change the type coloring. I'm running into some strange behavior when I do the above:

(1) As I type the type name, the coloring is as expected. But, when I finish typing, it reverts. (2) When I review the hover popup for the type name, the coloring is as expected.

Comment: Okay, I was able to test this and get it working by targeting `"type"` under `editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations`. See updated answer. It should apply immediately, but you may need to restart vs code with the `Reload Window` command.

Comment: Lovely! And, interface is also exposed! Just curious, how did you figure this out?

Comment: I just randomly typed keywords into the command palette until I found something useful. You can learn a lot about VS Code features that way.